# How to send data from blackberry to servlet

Tags: servlets, blackberry, http-post

I am using below code to send data to servlet

```
     HttpConnection c = (HttpConnection)Connector.open("http://localhost:8585/resposweb/resposweb?action=create_order;deviceside=true");

                            c.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
                            c.setRequestProperty("If-Modified-Since", "29 Oct 1999 19:43:31 GMT");
                            c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
                            c.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
                            os = (DataOutputStream)c.openDataOutputStream();

                            //byte[] res = net.rim.device.api.system.GPRSInfo.getIMEI();
                            os.writeUTF(ViewItems.isNewOrder());
                            os.writeUTF(OrderDetails.getOrderDtlAsString());
                            os.flush();    
                           os.close();
```

At server side i am  using below code to receive data from blackberry

```
 DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream((InputStream)request.getInputStream());
 String orderType = in.readUTF().trim();
 String mobdata = in.readUTF().trim();
```

but at server side i am getting below exception

```
java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
        at com.sath.resposweb.controller.ResPosController.processRequest(ResPosC
ontroller.java:52)
        at com.sath.resposweb.controller.ResPosController.doPost(ResPosControlle
r.java:189)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java
:849)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.proce
ss(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:45
4)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

can any one tell me how to send data to a servlet(java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **HttpConnection.GET** method to send the data through url while opening the connection.

Comment: dont only thanks if the answer is right you can accept it by clicking on the **Right mark**